Can the shapeshifter steal others' memories by touching them?
In The Boys, season 4, ep. 7, there is a shapeshifter superhuman, who shapeshifts / steals a person's appearance by touching them (I assume). As we see during the pursuit between this shapeshifter and The Boys in an apartment, this shapeshifter touches an old lady and shapeshifts into her appearance (off screen).
By the end of this episode, we see this shapeshifter steal Annie's appearance, have a conversation with Hughie on a topic that is private between the real Annie and Hughie, and the shapeshifter open up a safe with the correct password.
Can we establish the fact that this shapeshifter can steal a person's appearance as well as memories by touching them?

Not necessarily. Not an answer, but the shapeshifter is acting on the behest of the super-intelligent Sister Sage. Whilst memory stealing is a possibility, they could also have been spied upon for a while and the shapeshifter simply knew the answers.

My previous comment was made before the subsequent episode, which revealed that this supe does indeed have the ability to steal (or more rather, copy) other peoples memories.

From the final episode of season 4, it seems this shape shifter indeed can steal people's memory; Annie's memory, Annie's mother's memory and this shape shifter's primary school teacher memory were all stolen.
